# tensorflow CNN does not use all the images for training

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, image-classification

i have defined a tensorflow CNN as follows:

```
    import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(1, (9, 9), activation='relu', input_shape=(153, 204,1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((3, 3)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(2, (9,9), activation='tanh'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(2, (9,9), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation  = 'softmax'))
model.summary()
```

which i train using this command

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(image_list, behaviour, epochs=5, 
                    validation_data=(image_list, behaviour), verbose = 1)
```

(It was the initial commit so i didnt want to do train-test split yet, one block at a time)

The image_list has the dimensions :(1809, 153, 204, 1) with 1809 images of 153x204x1 pixels each
Behaviour can take any of the values 0,1,2

However i noticed something weird, namely during the training i get this

```
57/57 [==============================] - 19s 325ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.2537 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.2830
```

Why are there 57/57. Doesnt this imply that only 57 images are taken into account? Very predictably, loss = 0 but accuracy = 30% which roughly corresponds to the percentage of the first label in the dataset (which all 57 first images share)

How can i convince it to take more into account?
PS, I know about shuffling , i just want all the images in the training set to be used
Thank you all for your time
best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

57 is the number of iterations of each epoch.

You have 1809 images and the default size of batch is 32 (also images) - as it is not specified by you in the code ([see the documentation](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/)), so `cell(1809/batch_szie) = 57`.

As a result, all images are taken into account on each epoch, it just takes 57 steps (iterations) to complete.